# UserControl With Collection Of Controls Inside

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, customization

I need to create UserControl with collection of `<asp:ScriptReference />` inside. 
No more elements allowed(must be supported by designer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if you can nest child elements in the markup of a web user control?:

```
<uc1:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server">
    <ScriptReferences>
        ...
    </ScriptReferences>
</uc1:MyUserControl>
```

The answer to the above is **NO**. You can't nest child elements in a Web User Control. If you need that functionality, you can develop a custom server control. You'll need to use the `PersistenceMode` attribute to accomplish it.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public ScriptReferenceCollection ScriptReferences
{
    get
    {
        if (scriptReferenceCollection == null)
        {
            if (scriptReferenceArrayList == null)
            {
                this.EnsureChildControls();
                if (scriptReferenceArrayList == null)
                    scriptReferenceArrayList = new ArrayList();
            }
            scriptReferenceCollection = new ScriptReferenceCollection(scriptReferenceArrayList);
        }
        return scriptReferenceCollection;
    }
}
```